# Where is the documentation for the Dday Ical library?

Tags: dday, ical-dotnet

The website that used to host it no longer is valid:

[DDay Software](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)

I can't find the documentation anywhere else. Is there another copy of the documentation anywhere?

Comment: http://rbalajiprasad.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/mvc-c-create-ical-calendar-ics-feed.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17980/Adding-iCalendar-Support-to-Your-Program-Part

Comment: https://code.daypilot.org/68025/asp-net-event-calendar-export-to-icalendar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently taken over the dday.ical library after tracking down Doug Day, the original author, and I've renamed it to ical.net, and removed the copyright restrictions, and licensed it under the MIT license.

For now, its home is here:

https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net

Over the course of this weekend, that link will start to show some examples of basic usage: creating an event with a recurrence rule, if nothing else. The XML comments are wildly out of date/divergent from the state of the library. Fixes for those will be forthcoming as well so the API will become a little more discoverable via Intellisense.

And if you're consuming the library via nuget, you'll want to switch over to ical.net instead. It contains several bugfixes, and quite a few performance enhancements. Stuff like intellisense comment fixes will only show up in ical.net:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/

Comment: wow. you are a life saver and what a contribution to the developer community.